# Want to add skrill in php based website

Tags: integration, payment-gateway, currency

I want to integrate Skrill in my php based website. The thing is that, I am new to PHP and Web Development in general and I don't have enough knowledge to do it. Can anyone suggest a guide which is beginner friendly or at least easy to understand, so that I could integrate it?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, Skrill Doesn't have sandbox for testing payments.
What you need to do is, Create one merchant(business) account and one buyer(personal) account.
Then ask the Skrill Support team to convert them into testing accounts.
Mail them at merchantservices@skrill.com with the following.
The body of the email can be like:

```
Hi There,

I want to integrate your Skrill Payment gateway in my project.
I have gone through the guides and from there got to know that I have to ask for Test accounts.
So please convert the following accounts to test accounts.

Buyer account:

Email: ******@gmail.com

Customer ID: 5519****


Merchant account:

Email: *******@gmail.com

Customer ID: 5519****
```

Please don't get confuse with ****, we will mention full email address and customer id in the Email.

After converting the accounts they will revert you back.

At the end go through their [Integration Guide](https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/templates/main/res/material/documents/pdf/getting-started/skrill-integration-manual-en.pdf)
You can directly jump to point **2.1 Connecting to the Payment Gateway**

I hope it will help you. If not, revert back to me I will provide details on coding part.

Comment: Thank you Puneet. It really helped.

Comment: @Puneet this method is not working. Do you know an alternate method for skrill payment?

Comment: Hi is it possible to integrate both eWallet and payment processing at the same time ?I wanted to build a system that enables users(customers) to add amount to app wallet and use that wallet money to make payment to various business vendors registered to the same application.